# How to make metadata working when search by the site search box sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created some metadata columns for my library. I tried to search it through the site search box. But it doesn't work.

For an example: my metadata is Asia/Japan/Company. I set Company to my files. I searched for "Company". but no result.

[image]

Comment: You need to map that new column to managed property and check searchable. https://www.eliostruyf.com/making-columns-searchable-for-the-list-or-library-searchbox/

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want!! Basically, it works. But sometimes it not works well. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you started full crawl after mapping? In which cases does not work well?

Comment: I have tried full crawl. But nothing changes. I have some existing documents which have been set the company and titles correctly. After full crawl, only some of them could be searched using the company. By the way, before I tried your suggestions, I had found that sometimes the title does not work well, either. I have some similar title files, when I search the common words, it won't give all the results. My files names are like "AB01_ABC_ABC","AB01_ABC_ABC(DD漢字)","AB01_ABC_ABC (DD漢字)"